# This site can't be reached - Django

Tags: python, django, windows

After I created a virtual enviroment and the necessary files, I ran, `python manage.py runserver` and there was an error. This is what the terminal gave me: `C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe: can't open file: 'C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\pydjango\\django-project\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: You're probably trying to run `manage.py` file but you're not in the same folder where that file is located. You should ensure you `cd folder_name` to where `manage.py` is then run the `command` again.

Comment: I tried cd in the folder and then this is what happened:

Comment: The error is too long so I can't fit it all in here.